# Can't assign a new object to pointer pointer type in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, nul

Assigning a new object to a pointer pointer type in cpp crushes the program.
Code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
    int key;
    Node * nex;
};
int main(){
    Node * my_node = new Node;
    Node ** pp_node;
    *pp_node = my_node;

    return 0;
}
```

I think that the issue here is following: `pp_node` is null and by typing `*pp_node = my_node;` I am trying to dereference null but the question is how can I assign `my_node` to the pointer, `pp_node` is pointing at?

Comment: `Node **pp_node = &my_node;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pp_node` should contain the address of `my_node` , in order to have `pp_node` point at `my_node`(which is itself a pointer and holding an address).

```
#include <iostream>

    struct Node{
    int key_;
    Node * nex;
};

int main(){
    Node node={34, nullptr};
    Node* p_my_node = &node;
    Node** pp_node;
    pp_node = &p_my_node;
    std::cout<<(**pp_node).key_;
    return 0;
}
```

Now

- `p_my_node`is a piece of memory whose value(data it is holding) is address of `node`. So it points at `node`
- `pp_node` is a piece of memory whose value is address of `p_my_node`, So it points at `p_my_node`

the output of the code above is `34`, as we expected.

Answer (score 1):

`pp_node` is uninitialized. You need to initialize it first.

```
Node** pp_node = new Node*; 
*pp_node = my_node;
```